# User behavior prediction/analysis

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am trying to apply machine learning methods to predict/ analyze user's behavior. The data which I have is in the following format:

[data type](https://www.dropbox.com/s/guoxblnlc24pywm/Screen%20Shot%202018-08-11%20at%202.11.01%20PM.png?dl=0)

I am new to the machine learning, so I am trying to understand what I am doing makes sense or not. Now in the activity column, either I have two possibilities which I am representing as 0 or 1. Now in time column, I have time in a cyclic manner mapped to the range (0-24). Now at a certain time (onehot encoded) user performs an activity. If I use activity column as a target column in machine learning, and try to predict if at a certain time user will perform one activity or another, does it make sense or not?

The reason I am trying to predict activity is that if my model provides me some result about activity prediction and in real time a user does something else (which he has not been doing over the last week or so), I want to consider it as a deviation from normal behavior.

Am I doing right or wrong? any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is valid, but machine learning models are not 100 % accurate all the time. That is why "Accuracy" is defined for a model.

If you want to create high-performance predictive models then go for deep learning models because its performance improves over time with the increase in the size of training data sets.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great use case for a Classification problem. Since you have only few columns (features) in your dataset, i would say start with a simple Boosted Decision Tree Classification algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct, that's basically how fraud detection AI works in some cases, one option to pursue is to use the [decision tree model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), this may help to scale dynamically.

I was working on the same project but in a different direction, have a look maybe it can help :) https://github.com/dmi3coder/behaiv-java.